# Bootstrap collapse only expands

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the code below in my Rails 4 app. When I click the button, the table shows perfectly, but when I click the button again it doesn't retract. I've read similar questions that mention having conflicting Javascript, but I'm not sure if that's it.

Here's my code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#years">Filter
</button>

<div id="years" class="collapse">
   <br />
   <div class="rating_table col-lg-4">
    <table class= "table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
      <th colspan="4">Filter By Year</th>
    <tr>
      <td><strong><%= link_to '2000', tens2000_user_path(@user) %></strong></td>
      <td><strong><%= link_to '2001', tens2001_user_path(@user) %></strong></td>    
      <td><strong><%= link_to '2002', tens2002_user_path(@user) %></strong></td>
      <td><strong><%= link_to '2003', tens2003_user_path(@user) %></strong></td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong><%= link_to '2004', tens2004_user_path(@user) %></strong></td>
      <td><strong><%= link_to '2005', tens2005_user_path(@user) %></strong></td>    
      <td><strong><%= link_to '2006', tens2006_user_path(@user) %></strong></td>
      <td><strong><%= link_to '2007', tens2007_user_path(@user) %></strong></td>    
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong><%= link_to '2008', tens2008_user_path(@user) %></strong></td>
      <td><strong><%= link_to '2009', tens2009_user_path(@user) %></strong></td>    
      <td><strong><%= link_to '2010', tens2010_user_path(@user) %></strong></td>    
      <td><strong><%= link_to '2011', tens2011_user_path(@user) %></strong></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>    
 </div>
```

My application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.masonry.min.js
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: I removed the second require bootstrap, since it seems that was pointless. It didn't help though.

Comment: Do you found an answer on this question? I've got the same problem.

Comment: @M.B. Just recently I did an update to the Bootstrap gems that I'm using (bootstrap-sass ~> 3.1.1.0 and twitter-bootstrap-rails ~> 3.2.0) and it worked. It must have been a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found out, that it was my mistake. For me it works well with bootstrap-sass 3.3.1. initialising with:  $('.collapse').collapse({ toggle: false });